# Fullpage.js menu doesn't work

Tags: fullpage.js

I have problem with fullpage.js. I have a top menu with links to the selectors like that

```
            <ul>
                <li data-menuanchor="Onas"><a href="#Onas">O nas</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="Aktualnosci"><a href="#Aktualnosci">Aktualności</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="Treningi"><a href="#Treningi">Treningi</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="Partnerzy"><a href="#Partnerzy">Partnerzy</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="Kontakt"><a href="#Kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
```

and

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                sectionsColor: ['black','black','black','black', 'black'],
                anchors: ['Onas', 'Aktualnosci', 'Treningi', 'Partnerzy', 'Kontakt'],
                css3: true,
                navigation: true,
                menu: '#menu',
                scrollingSpeed: 700,
                sectionSelector: ".section",
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My problem is when I click on element of menu, menu switch page one more than need. It good works when going back.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not violenting this rule detailed in fullpage.js docs:

> Be careful! data-anchor tags can not have the same value as any ID element on the site (or NAME element for IE).

And that your HTML mark-up is the needed one (with no other elements between `sections`)

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional detail to make Alvaro's answer more useful: The "Be careful!" warning complains if the anchors (as assigned in the fullPage.js configuration) are added to the div.section elements as id= or name= values -- just like it says. This seems like a harmless warning (how else would the fullPage.js know where to find the targets?), but it is actually an error. So the id= and name= attributes must NOT be explicitly declared in the div.section elements. fullPage.js will know how to locate them by their order of occurrence.

Summary: Believe the warning! Do not set id= or name= attributes in the anchor target divs.